# How to install the Finder Sync Extension so that it's persistently integrated with Finder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, findersync

In my app I have Finder Sync Extension. I know how to launch it using `pluginkit -a`.
The problem is when I run from Xcode it launches and works. But I need this to be bundled with the main app and the main app should launch it. I used `terminal` command to achieve it, but it doesn't work.

I read few blogs and got to know, the plugin/extension/.appex needs to be registered to finder. How do I register it?

Comment: macOS will automatically launch your plugin. Is it code signed? Do you see any error in the console related to your plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to launch a finder extension manually. The system will launch a finder extension for you. You just need to enable it in system preferences.

> The system may also launch additional copies of your extension
>   whenever an Open or Save dialog is displayed.

Have a look at [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html) for more details.